# How to select data from dates range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, datetimeindex

I have the following datetime index and dataframe object:

```
dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-02', '2019-06-16', '2019-07-07', '2019-07-21', '2019-08-04'], name='Date')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], index=dti,
                  data={
                      'Open': [1.27223, 1.27340, 1.26976, 1.25736, 1.23806],
                      'High': [1.27223, 1.27340, 1.26976, 1.25736, 1.23806],
                      'Low': [1.27223, 1.27340, 1.26976, 1.25736, 1.23806],
                      'Close': [1.27223, 1.27340, 1.26976, 1.25736, 1.23806]
                  })
```

It is a weekly based data, each bar is a weekly bar on a finance market.
I would like to select daily bars for each df row, for example

```
2019-06-16: [2019-06-10, 2019-06-11, ..., 2019-06-16]
2019-07-07: [2019-07-01, 2019-07-02, ..., 2019-07-07]
...
```

at the end it should be a list of dataframes.
All data from daily bars exists.

**The question for me is** how to find a start date of weekly bar, then I could use slicing , like [from_date:to_date]

**And second issue is** that it can be not only weekly bars, it could be any other period: monthly, quarterly, ...

When I had ordered continuous series of dates, I've used Boolean operations, but here this approach doesn't work:

```
# get components values range
comp_res = comp[(comp.index > _from) & (comp.index <= _to)]
```

Comment: not clear what the expected out is. please put the expected out put as a table or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.Series.to_period`:

```
pd.Series(df.index).dt.to_period('w').dt.start_time
```

Output:

```
0   2019-05-27
1   2019-06-10
2   2019-07-01
3   2019-07-15
4   2019-07-29
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: It is almost what I was looking for...Thank you!
Is there a way to use '2w', '3w' etc ?